# Sharing Collection Data Contracts

Tags: wcf, proxy, datacontracts

I have some WCF services and have separated out the data contracts for these services into their own assembly. I then have a client of the services that references the data contracts assembly.

I have turned on the option to *Reuse types in referenced assemblies*. This works, but not for collections. The proxy generator instead generates its own version of collections, even though that version is *exactly* the same as the one in my data contracts assembly.

**Is there any way to tell the proxy generator to reuse the collections defined in my data contracts assembly rather than generating its own, redundant collection types?**

Answer (score 0):

If you have controll of both the server and the client, you do not need to generate a provy.

There is a good explaination in this [screencast](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122).

We have stopped using generated proxies. We have saved weeks of work compared with continually having to update the generated proxies, and debugging when the problem was that someone forgot to update the proxy.

Comment: OK, assume I don't have control of the server and don't have access to the service contract - only the data contracts.